# Detecting when person wearing an Apple Watch falls

Tags: apple-watch, core-motion

If I drop my Apple Watch and catch it before it hits the ground, the app I'm making should detect that the watch has fallen. But that's not happening. What's wrong with the code below? Thanks!

```
let motion = CMMotionManager()
if motion.isDeviceMotionAvailable {
     motion.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.1
     motion.startDeviceMotionUpdates()
     if let deviceMotion = motion.deviceMotion {
          let accelerationX = deviceMotion.gravity.x + deviceMotion.userAcceleration.x
          let accelerationY = deviceMotion.gravity.y + deviceMotion.userAcceleration.y
          let accelerationZ = deviceMotion.gravity.z + deviceMotion.userAcceleration.z
          let totalAcceleration = sqrt((accelerationX * accelerationX) + (accelerationY * accelerationY) + (accelerationZ * accelerationZ))

          if totalAcceleration >  9.0 {
               print("Watch has fallen")
          }
    }
    motion.stopDeviceMotionUpdates()
}
```

Comment: Have you tried logging some of the data? It's possible you aren't hitting the total acceleration that you're expecting.

Comment: Please see Palash's answer below and my comment below it for details. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[`motion.deviceMotion`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmmotionmanager/1616040-devicemotion) will just get the latest sample of device-motion data.

So, this might just fetch the data once on when you run it. You will probably need something like a timer to check the acceleration.

Something like this(taken from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/getting_raw_accelerometer_events)

```
let motion = CMMotionManager()

func startAccelerometers() {
   // Make sure the accelerometer hardware is available. 
   if self.motion.isAccelerometerAvailable {
      self.motion.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 1.0 / 60.0  // 60 Hz
      self.motion.startAccelerometerUpdates()

      // Configure a timer to fetch the data.
      self.timer = Timer(fire: Date(), interval: (1.0/60.0), 
            repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
         // Get the accelerometer data.
         if let data = self.motion.accelerometerData {
            let x = data.acceleration.x
            let y = data.acceleration.y
            let z = data.acceleration.z

            // Use the accelerometer data in your app.
         }
      })

      // Add the timer to the current run loop.
      RunLoop.current.add(self.timer!, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
   }
}
```

Alternatively, you can also pass a handler to [`startDeviceMotionUpdates`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmmotionmanager/1616176-startdevicemotionupdates), which will be called based on [`deviceMotionUpdateInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmmotionmanager/1616065-devicemotionupdateinterval).

Comment: The point at which I use the accelerometer data in my app, after writing something like "var x = Measurement(value: data.acceleration.x, unit: UnitAcceleration.gravity)
                            x = x.converted(to: .metersPerSecondSquared)" for x, y, and z, and letting "let totalAcceleration = sqrt((x.value * x.value) + (y.value * y.value) + (z.value * z.value))", I get a value that is consistently around 9.8 m/s^2 when the watch is not in free fall. Why is this? What value should I check for to detect it being in free fall?

Comment: Hey did you get any reason for the 9.8 m/s^2  ?

Comment: Why are you converting to UnitAcceleration.gravity? It should work fine without it, should probably just use metersPerSecondSquared.
@UmarFarooque 9.8 m/s^2 is the acceleration due to gravity on earth, which is what might be added to the accelerometer value. Didn't try this though.